# Charge distribution on a hollow conducting cube

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors

Suppose we have a charged hollow conducting  cube, will the charge be uniformly distributed over the surface of the cube?

I know that the electric field will be zero everywhere inside the cube but to produce that zero field inside, should the charge distribution be uniform over the surface of the cube?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I think that the charge distribution will not be uniform since the surface is not spherical .i only want a picture of the charge distribution .

Comment: Also it baffles me that the charge distribution will not be uniform on such a uniform shape such as a cube

Comment: thinking about the different kinds of symmetries in the 2 cases might help you understand why the charge distributions are different.